# Rails: After putting devise routes in namespace, the name of model are prefixed with the namespace. How to remove it?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I am using devise for authentication in my Rails RESTFul API service. Devise enables me to create a new user using `[POST] http://domain/users` with form_data:

```
[user]password = 123
[user]email = foo@bar.zoo
[user]password_confirmation = 123
```

Then I put `devise_for` in namespace like this

```
namespace :api do
  namespace :v1 do
    devise_for :users,
               controllers: {
                   :registrations => 'api/v1/registrations',
                   :sessions => 'api/v1/sessions',
                   :passwords => 'api/v1/passwords'
               }
  end
end
```

The file structure of controllers looks like this.

```
.
├── api
│   └── v1
│       ├── passwords_controller.rb
│       ├── registrations_controller.rb
│       └── sessions_controller.rb
├── application_controller.rb
```

After I made this change, I should use `[POST] http://domain/api/v1/users` to create a new user, but with the following form_data

```
[api_v1_user]password = 123
[api_v1_user]email = foo@bar.zoo
[api_v1_user]password_confirmation = 123
```

I don't want the model name (i.e. **user**) to be prefixed by **api_v1_**. Because if someday I switched my api version to **v2**, then I have to update all my client side API call!

Any ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can try the following in your routes

```
namespace :api, as: nil do
  namespace :v1, as: nil do |version|
    devise_for :users,
               controllers: {
                   :registrations => "api/#{version}/registrations",
                   :sessions => "api/#{version}/sessions",
                   :passwords => "api/#{version}/passwords"
               }
  end
end
```

Answer (score 3):

Check out devise [Configuring Routes](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#configuring-routes) doc. You can achieve this by customizing the api routes yourself. E.g

```
namespace :api do
  namespace :v1 do
   devise_scope :user do
    resources :sessions,        defaults: {format: :json}
    resources :registrations,   defaults: {format: :json}
   end
 end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using custom devise controllers, so you should be able to set the warden authentication scope in your controller:

```
warden.authenticate!(scope: :user)
```

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this while trying to use the Versionist gem to version custom Devise authentication strategies (Rails 5). Here is my solution for setting it up in configuration without requiring a custom controller:

/config/initializers/inflections.rb gets an inflector so API doesn't keep showing up as Api. its a nice-to-have

```
ActiveSupport::Inflector.inflections(:en) do |inflect|
  inflect.acronym 'API'
end
```

routes.rb

```
api_version(:module => "API::V1",:path => {:value => "api/v1"}) do
  devise_for  :users,
              :as => :fancy, #removes "api_v1" from the derived model scope, but it cant be blank so pick something that doesn't contain the version.
              :path => "", #removes "users" from the path so it is just "api/:ver/login"
              :path_names => { sign_in: 'login', sign_out: 'logout'} #changes the 'action' part of the path name, just flavour.
  end
  #if you need a scope, you must now include the scope you choose in devise_for :as. for example:
  devise_scope :fancy_user do
    #helper route so we can test with a logout link or url using GET
    get :logout, :controller => :sessions, :action => :destroy
  end
end
```

This will also set you up to add your own custom authentication strategy and plays nice with solutions like 4TRABE's remote authentication http://4trabes.com/2012/10/31/remote-authentication-with-devise/ Now you can have nicely versioned custom external API authentication. Of course we can add a custom controller as well, but it's not necessary to wrangle the version number out of the scope.

Just remember that since you changed the scope you would need to reference it that way when you register it wit warden. ie. initializers/devise.rb ends up like:

```
config.warden do |manager|
  manager.strategies.add(:remote_authenticatable, Devise::Strategies::RemoteAuthenticatable)
  manager.default_strategies(:scope => :fancy_user).unshift :remote_authenticatable
end
config.add_module :remote_authenticatable, :controller => :sessions, :route => { :session => :routes }
```

Hope this helps someone, enjoy ^_^